# Change the orientation of just one page in Libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm trying to change the second page of my document from portrait to landscape orientation without affecting the rest.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/971530/change-page-orientation-of-one-specific-page) question but none of the referenced tips work because they were from Libreoffice 4 and I'm on 7.0.4.2. I've been trying things for a good 15 minutes and am out of inspiration/luck. Any help is appreciated!
Also, I'm on Linux if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following steps were tested with LO 6.4.7.2 Linux Mint), 7.0.4.2 (Windows) and 7.1 (Windows):

1. Put the cursor at the end of page **1** (!).
2. Menu "Insert" -> "More breaks" -> "Manual Break..."
3. Type: "Page break"; Style: "Landscape"; -> "OK".
4. Put the cursor at the end of page **2** (which should be in landscape orientation);
5. Repeat step 2;
6. Repeat step 3, select Style "Default Style" instead of landscape.

Now, You should have a document of at least three pages, with only page 2 in landscape orientation. Finally, move the content from the previous page 2 (now page 4) to the new page 2, and the content from the following page to page 3.

Screenshot from LO 6.4.7.2 on Linux:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't look like I have "More breaks" in my insert menu

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment but here's the menu I see when my cursor is at the end of the first page: https://imgur.com/a/Ufkx2XO

Comment: @belkarx: Sorry, i can't explain this. The screenshot above shows the menu entry from 6.4 on Linux, it's the same on LO 7.

Comment: Realized my issue; I was using Libreoffice Draw which is kind of (https://superuser.com/questions/1259704/how-can-i-open-pdf-files-in-libreoffice-writer-rather-than-draw) the only software that can open PDFs and I think your answer is for LO Writer?

Comment: Yes, i assumed you're talking about a odt (text) file - sorry! To rotate a single page of a  PDF file, you may use a tool like PDFShuffler / PDFArranger which is most likely part of your linux distribution.